# How to force ASP.NET Web API to always return JSON?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET Web API does content negotiation by default - will return XML or JSON or other type based on the `Accept` header. I don't need / want this, is there a way (like an attribute or something) to tell Web API to always return JSON?

Comment: You may be able to do this removing all formatters except json from `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[Supporting only JSON in ASP.NET Web API – **THE RIGHT WAY**](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/)

Replace IContentNegotiator with JsonContentNegotiator:

```
var jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
//optional: set serializer settings here
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
```

JsonContentNegotiator implementation:

```
public class JsonContentNegotiator : IContentNegotiator
{
    private readonly JsonMediaTypeFormatter _jsonFormatter;

    public JsonContentNegotiator(JsonMediaTypeFormatter formatter) 
    {
        _jsonFormatter = formatter;    
    }

    public ContentNegotiationResult Negotiate(
            Type type, 
            HttpRequestMessage request, 
            IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
    {
        return new ContentNegotiationResult(
            _jsonFormatter, 
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}
```

Comment: where does the first part of the code get cut and pasted too? I don't see a "config" object in my Global.asax. Where is that variable coming from? the article doesn't explain either.

Comment: Check public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) { ... } method in WebApiConfig.cs file which has been gererated by VS2012 on project creation

Comment: Will this force JSON in the sense that a client `Accept`ing XML will get JSON, and **will not get a 406**?

Comment: I can answer my own comment/question: it returns XML whatever the `Accept` header.

Comment: This breaks my swashbuckle integration and it seems it is related to this issue on github ( https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/219 ). I'd like to use this method but the one below using `GlobalConfiguration...Clear()` actually works.

Answer (score 174):

Clear all formatters and add Json formatter back.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

**EDIT**

I added it to `Global.asax` inside `Application_Start()`.

Comment: and in which file..?? global.ascx..??

Comment: In your Application_Start() method

Comment: Filip W just got better way now :), see it here http://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/

Comment: @TienDo - linking to Filip's own blog?

Comment: The settings could be better put in `App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs` file.

Answer (score 11):

Philip W had the right answer but for clarity and a complete working solution, edit your Global.asax.cs file to look like this: (Notice I had to add the reference System.Net.Http.Formatting to the stock generated file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace BoomInteractive.TrainerCentral.Server {
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {
        protected void Application_Start() {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            //Force JSON responses on all requests
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
```

This clears the XML formatter and thus defaulting to JSON format.

Comment: Perfect all that is needed

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Dmitry Pavlov's excellent answer, I altered it slightly so I could plug-in whatever formatter I wanted to enforce.

Credit to Dmitry.

```
/// <summary>
/// A ContentNegotiator implementation that does not negotiate. Inspired by the film Taken.
/// </summary>
internal sealed class LiamNeesonContentNegotiator : IContentNegotiator
{
    private readonly MediaTypeFormatter _formatter;
    private readonly string _mimeTypeId;

    public LiamNeesonContentNegotiator(MediaTypeFormatter formatter, string mimeTypeId)
    {
        if (formatter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("formatter");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mimeTypeId))
            throw new ArgumentException("Mime type identifier string is null or whitespace.");

        _formatter = formatter;
        _mimeTypeId = mimeTypeId.Trim();
    }

    public ContentNegotiationResult Negotiate(Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
    {
        return new ContentNegotiationResult(_formatter, new MediaTypeHeaderValue(_mimeTypeId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This has correct headers set. Seems a bit more elegant.

```
public JsonResult<string> TestMethod() 
{
return Json("your string or object");
}
```

Comment: What are the fully qualified names for the JsonResult and Json classes?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do that for one method only, then declare your method as returning `HttpResponseMessage` instead of `IEnumerable<Whatever>` and do:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAllWhatever()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new List<Whatever>(), Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
    }
```

this code is pain for unit testing but that's also possible like this:

```
    sut = new WhateverController() { Configuration = new HttpConfiguration() };
    sut.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new Mock<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().Object);
    sut.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
```

Comment: If you want something for a method only create an http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1):

for those using OWIN

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

becomes (in Startup.cs):

```
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OwinConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            OwinConfiguration.Formatters.Clear();
            OwinConfiguration.Formatters.Add(new DynamicJsonMediaTypeFormatter());

            [...]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<MeineObjekt> Get()
    {
        return Json(new MeineObjekt()
        {
            Cod = "C4666",               
            Payment = 10.0m,
            isEnough = false
        });
    }
```