# Owin/WebApi force to to accept only application/json Accept and Content-Type headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I need to configure my Owin self-host to accept only `application/json` Accept and Content-Type headers. For any other `Accept` received from client (for example `application/xml`) i want to return an Http 415 Unsupported Media Type).

I've tried all solutions but none of them seem to work. http://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/

I tried to clear all formatters in my `HttpConfiguration` and add only the Json one:

```
configuration.Formatters.Clear();
configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Doesn't work, it still returns `200 Ok` for any media type.

I've tried to replace the `DefaultContentNegotiator` with my own `JsonContentNegotiator` as in the example from the link above, still with no luck.

I ended up with the solution that i'm myself verifying the headers in my Controller. But that's a pretty ugly solution. Is there any way to achieve this with webapi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force ASP.NET Web API to always return JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629144/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-always-return-json)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using [delegate handlers](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)?

```
public class MediaTypeDelegatingHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Headers.Accept.Contains(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json")) == false)
        {
            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MediaTypeDelegatingHandler());
    }
```

I haven't tried the code but if you don't have a solution yet you can give it a try.