# How to configure .NET Core API to always return JSON

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I've created a .NET Core API.  If I set the endpoint to return an object, it currently successfully returns it in JSON as desired.  If the return type of the endpoint is `void`, however, it gives a 200 response, but the response header is `text/html` instead of `application/json`.

How can I configure my .NET Core API to always give a response with a JSON header?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629144/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-always-return-json).

Comment: @dcg I've applied that on a .NET 4.5 Web API, but I didn't think that would work for .NET Core.

Comment: I think this is responsibility of consumer of your API. They can put the type of response they want in request's `Accept` header.

Comment: In addition to Fabio (Accept header is correct), how are you seeing that it's returning "text/html"?

Comment: Why is the return type void? Why not return an ActionResult and then return a Json() result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return JsonResult type, like

```
// GET: api/authors
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Get()
{
    return Json(_authorRepository.List());
}
```

[more is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting)

Comment: What library are you using to be able to use "return Json(.....);" method?

Comment: Hi @MC9000 there is a link in my answer ;-) It's a part of AspNetCore to be precise Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller.Json()
If you the compiler cannot find this method you can double check that your controller extends Controller class, e.g.
public class AuthorsController : Controller

Answer (score 1):

add a filter of type  ProducesAttribute("application/json") to the ConfigureServices. In the Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new ProducesAttribute("application/json"));
            });
    }
```