# How to configure ASP.NET Core to return exceptions in camel case?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When my application throws an unhandled exception, I return a status code 500 (internal server error), as in this example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Get()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Exception return test.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex);
    }
}
```

The JSON return is:

```
{
  "ClassName": "System.Exception",
  "Message": "Exception return test.",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": null,
  "HResult": -2146233088,
  "Source": null,
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

But I want all properties formatted in camel case.

In ASP.NET Web API you could implement a `IContentNegotiator` interface and replace it in your `HttpConfiguration`, like [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629144/how-to-force-asp-net-web-api-to-always-return-json#18145616). With this configuration, every output from the API is in camel case, including exception messages.

In ASP.NET Core 2.2, even though object properties return by the API are in camel case by default, exceptions aren't.

I tried (in Startup.cs):

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        options.UseCamelCasing(true);
    })
```

but no luck. I also inspected the `OutputFormatters` and confirmed that the `JsonOutputFormatter` already had `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` as its ContractResolver. I tried it anyway, but as expected, no change in the results:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        foreach (var item in options.OutputFormatters)
        {
            if (item is JsonOutputFormatter a)
            {
                // This was pointless
                a.PublicSerializerSettings.ContractResolver 
                    = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: At least some of the JSON properties correspond directly to the properties of an `Exception`. If it's intended to be mapped to an `Exception`, mangling the case would be lossy.

Comment: Have you thought about using your own middleware for exception handling?

Comment: What json serializer are you using?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski that sounds interesting, but since I'm starting out with .net core, I have no idea how I can use a middleware to change the casing of the resulting JSON.

Comment: @insane_developer the default one, I haven't changed it.

Comment: @MarcosDimitrio Basically it allows you to write a custom error response and control casing of JSON and other things, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630076/asp-net-core-web-api-exception-handling) can be used as starting point