# Display the fields of the class in order by position in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have this class:

```
public class Presenter
{
    public int? Society { get; set; }

    public int? SenderCode { get; set; }

    public string BusinessNameSender { get; set; }

    public string AddressSender { get; set; }

    public string VatNumberSender { get; set; }

    public string Check { get; set; }   
}
```

Retrieve the data with a query and with the `ExtractField` method populate the `Presenter` class

```
public static IEnumerable<Presenter> ExtractField(IEnumerable<dynamic> query)
{
    return query.Select(x => new Presenter()
    {
        Society = x.ids.Society ?? null,
        SenderCode = x.ids.SenderCode ?? null,
        BusinessNameSender = x.details.Sender,
        AddressSender = x.details.DestinationAddress,
        VatNumberSender = x.details.VatNumberSender,
        Check = x.ids.Check,
    });
}
```

When I then use the `ToList()` to then display the result on the screen within the list, the fields are sorted alphabetically, how do I make sure that the fields are seen in the order I have set?

I used dynamic because having two distinct queries but which have the same select seemed to me the best way not to duplicate code

Comment: Where do you display it? Console? How are you outputing it?

Comment: I display the result in a json (the application is a Rest API)

Comment: Have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330989/order-of-serialized-fields-using-json-net ?

Comment: Debugger always show Properties/members alphabetically. json serializing should maintain the order, how the class is coded

Comment: If you are using Json.NET to serialize data then you can take advantage of [JsonPropertyAttribute's Order property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyOrder.htm) to define custom ordering.

Comment: I don't think he wants to use custom order, he wants it the way, the class is defined but is confused by the debugger always sorting alphabetically... but maybe I misunderstood him :)