# Default order JSON.Net

Tags: json.net, system.text.json

System.Text.Json does not guarantee the serialization order of properties. JSON.Net has the same behavior ?

I want to know json.net default serialization order

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of serialized fields using JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330989/order-of-serialized-fields-using-json-net)

Comment: I i dont specify the order, can the serializer bring in any order ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.